# download a paginated report to csv

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

' cache-control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
content-length: 340
content-type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
location: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/e022ff17-01f0-49a9-a709-20f4ccd22a92/exports/Mi9CbG9iSWRWMi0zYmQxZmM1Yy04OGM4LTRiN2ItOTE2ZS0yMmJmN2ViZDMyZjVqODl0Li4=
pragma: no-cache
requestid: 943164dd-2224-4cb6-aa0b-c8ff8e80181d  '

I get this as Ouptut.But how to export csv using this output.